# finding the volume by solving the double integrals: $\int_{-2}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} |x|\sin(\pi y) dydx$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have to integrate and describe of what region in $R^3$ they represent the volumes.

1) $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2} 4-x^2-y^2 dxdy$

2) $\displaystyle\int_{-2}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} |x|\sin(\pi y) dydx$

Solution:

1)$\int_{0}^{2} 4x-\frac{x^3}{3}-xy^2 dy$ ;integrating w.r.t x

$\int_{0}^{2} \frac{32}{3} - 4y^2 dy$ ;inserting valuyes of x

$\frac{32y}{3}-\frac{4y^3}{3}$ ; integrating w.r.t y

$\frac{32}{3}$ ; inserting values of y

The region should be a paraboloid over a rectangle $R$={${(x,y)\epsilon R^2 | 0<=y<=2,-2<=x<=2}$}.

Is this correct? because I drew the graph and found that the volume is not always non-negative. I have similarly found the volume for part 2, and its region should be something over a rectangle R$={${(x,y)\epsilon R^2 | 0<=y<=1,-2<=x<=3}$} but I don't know what that something is.

Comment: Part one is correct to me!

Comment: For part 2, can you find the answer without geometric view of the region?

Comment: You can use http://grapher.mathpix.com/ to get a really good view of the surface you're integrating under in part 2, but I'm at just as much of a loss for how to describe that surface...

Comment: @user108128 I found the volume for both without a need for geometric view. But when I tried plotting them I found out that part 1, some of the volume is below xy-plane, that is why I'm confused if the answer is true or not

Comment: I don't think so, the region is over $xy$ plane and the volume is $$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2}\int_0^{4-x^2-y^2}dz dxdy$$

Comment: @user108128 as I have not studied triple integration yet, I can't say anything about that, but as for volume below $xy-pane$ I can explain that. At $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ the paraboloid meets the $xy-pane$ and its shape on $xy-plane$ is a circle. But we are finding the area over a rectangle, so some of the area is below the plane.

Comment: I think you are right. my mistake. sorry